# jquery load only innerHtml instead of wrapper itself

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Let me clarify my need, it might not be all clear from the title.

I am using:

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/page1.html #content");
```

When I look in firebug I see #content inside #content on the page where Ajax call occurred.
So it's obvious that I need only #content's inner html to get loaded. What would be the most elegant way to achieve this with Jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Use the Child Selector (http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) on #content to select all (*) the children of #content.

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/page1.html #content > *");
```

Comment: It would be nice if your answer also included an explanation.

Answer (score 10):

that can be done using `$.get`

```
$.get('http://example.com/page1.html', function (data) {
    data = $(data).find('#content').html();
    $("#content").empty().append(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It looks promising but somehow all I get now is empty #content????

Comment: Yes, of course. I've changed it to `link` `var link=$(this).attr("href");` As an example link value is `http://www.george.destrodesign.com/?page_id=33`.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba if you do log for `data` do you get anything

Comment: Actually when I execute `alert($(data).find("#content").html());` I get `null`

Comment: @daniel.tosaba it's not `..find("content")..` but `find("#content")`

Comment: I know.. fixed it but still same problem.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba maybe you're using old jquery version

Comment: I might have it wrapped wrongly. Will take a closer look, and let you know ASAP. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't find any irregularities with wrapping but let me ask you something that I get while executing `alert()`:  When I do `alert(data)` page's code pops up, but when I execute `alert($(data).html())` I get `null`. Does that seem weird to you?

Comment: I am using JQuery version 1.7.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10356/discussion-between-daniel-tosaba-and-mgraph)